# How can I line up top and bottom photos of a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a PCB. I have some photos of the top and bottom, but lining them up is tricky as they were taken free-hand. Is there an easy way to line them up?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with GIMP (free & open source!) fairly easily with the **Handle Transform** tool (skip to Step 9 if you have layers kinda-aligned).

1. Start by opening both sides of the image with the "Open as Layers..." command

   [image: File -> Open as Layers...]
2. For some fudge room, give the canvas some extra room. Image (1) → Canvas Size (2), expand the width/height to 200% (3), center it (4), and resize (5)

   [image]
3. Pick the image you want to use as a reference. It doesn't really matter which, but I'd pick the one that looks the best and is maybe the least-distorted. Clicking the eye icon on the layers can let you hide/show that layer. In the below image, I named the layers, and decided I was going to use the AMP-side as the reference, so I dragged it to the bottom.

   > If you're missing the Layers tool dock, go to Windows → Dockable Dialogs → Layers (Ctrl + L)

   [image]
4. With that image on the bottom, select the top layer, make it visible (1), lower the opacity to 80%ish or whatever looks good (2) and *roughly* align it. At the very least, you'll need to flip it horizontally or vertically. Here, I selected the move tool (3) and offset the image a little (4).

   [image]
5. These are the two rough holes I'll use. Because I flipped the board top-to-bottom relative to my camera, I'll need to vertically flip the image

   [image]
6. With the top (layer to transform) layer selected, pick Layer (1) → Transform (2) → then whatever options you need to do. Depending on how your photos were aligned, you may need to 90° rotate one way or the other, then flip horizontally/vertically. I just did vertical. (3)

   > Note: ensure you're picking the **Layer** menu so you only modify one layer, not both.

   [image]
7. Now the holes are roughly close, and moving the top layer gets them roughly good-enough.

   [image]
8. Nudged a bit.

   [image]
9. Select the tool that makes this work: **Handle Transform** (Shift + T).

   [image]
10. We need to select 2+ points on the top layer, and tell GIMP where they go on the bottom. The more accurate the better, so small vias would be best. Also, we want them to be roughly on the corners of the image to minimize extrapolation error. Here I'm toggling visibility of the top layer, and have identified some vias on both sides, around the large lower mounting hole.

    [image]

    - I marked the top and bottom layers with little carats (^) pointing at pairs of features I'll align. This is optional, but can make it easier when the tool is active. While doing the transform, you *can toggle the toper layer visibility and opacity*, ***but*** you'll also have a ghost image of how the layer looked before transformation, so you'll wind up looking at 3 layers! With the markers, you'll need less fussing.

      - [image]
      - [image]
      - [image]
    - Because GIFs can only go so far, here's the big finish in video form. I start off by going to the three sets of points I marked, dragging blue (top layer) to red (bottom). I do the final corner which is slightly off due to distortion by just picking one (they're pretty close now) and dragging it so it and all it's neighbors look good. **Click Transform** and it'll tweak your top layer!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC1b-9xASkw

Here's the final aligned image. Pretty good for two photos.

[image]